# How to do output of both variable and it's value to a file

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, variable

I'm struggling a bit with this task, for example I can do a simple loop to send variables values into a file with for loop. But how to get something before output of the variable value? I did something like this as a workaround:

```
list="$1\n$2\n$3"
varNames=$'var1=\nvar2=\nvar3='


for i in $varNames $list; do
    echo -e $varNames$list > "vars-$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M).file"
done
```

But I cant get the loop correct to iterate through out every item in both lists,but the output I'm getting is:

```
var1= var2= var3=$1
$2
$3
```

As above $1,$2,$3 are correct values of variables that I created before.
What I'm missing in this loop?
Is it good way to create two lists or it can handled by some sed afterwards?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you check the example code you showed us? For example, you loop using a variable `i` but you never use it in the actual loop. Currently, you would simply execute your `echo` statement as many times as there are elements in `$varNames` and `$list`

Comment: Sorry I made an error while editing. Now the output is right. What i want to accomplish is to have var1=$1 and so on in new lines respectively.
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll check out how goes with array keys and I hope it will work out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are almost as many issues as you have lines in your script, I try to go through one by one, at each step assuming everything else is working as intended.

1.

```bsh
list="$1\n$2\n$3"
```

This won't work, because the `\n` will not be replaced by newline, you would need something like this:

```bsh
list="$1"$'\n'"$2"$'\n'"$3"
```

or

```
list="$1
$2
$3"
```

2.

```bsh
for i in $varNames $list; do
```

Assuming you fixed (1), this loop will run 6 times (Disclaimer, see last sentence of this). One time for each of `$varNames` and `$list`, which I don't think is intended. Also, when you loop like this, the variables will not be split by newline, but by [`$IFS`](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$IFS). It defaults to newline, space or tab. So it works, but knowing that, you could also just use `list="$1 $2 $3"` in (1). This only works of course, if you know each of these variables don't contain any of newline, space or tab.

3.

```bsh
echo -e $varNames$list
```

outputs the whole variables and not just the split up parts which would be `$i`.

4.

You overwrite the whole file for each iteration. Better use

```bsh
for ...; do ... done > file
```

---

**So what now?**

I think you cannot easily fix your code as is. Instead, you should use bash arrays and iterate over the keys:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

list=("$1" "$2" "$3")
varNames=("var1" "var2" "var3")

for k in "${!varNames[@]}"; do
    printf '%s=%s\n' "${varNames[$k]}" "${list[$k]}"
done > "vars-$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M).file"
```

I prefer using `printf` ([see this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)), but you could also use `echo` like this instead if you don't care ...

```
echo "${varNames[$k]}=${list[$k]}"
```